# 'xdom is not defined' error within autopulous-xdom2jso

Tags: json, angular, typescript, xml-parsing, angular2-services

I have imported below packages in my service, which I use for SOAP-API processing.

```
"autopulous-xdom": "~0.0.12"
"autopulous-xdom2jso": "^0.0.12"
```

I am trying to use these with below lines at top of my service.ts

```
import 'autopulous-xdom/xdom.js';
import 'autopulous-xdom2jso/xdom2jso.js';

import convert = xdom2jso.convert;
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SoapService {
    constructor() {}
}
```

I get no errors on compiling and building. But while running the application in browser, I get below error.

[image]

Has anyone worked with [xdom2jso](https://github.com/autopulous/xdom2jso) and [xdom](https://github.com/autopulous/xdom)? Please help.

Comment: I even tried packages  "autopulous-xdom": "0.0.6", "autopulous-xdom2jso": "0.0.10", and imported them as import xdom from 'autopulous-xdom';
import xdom2jso from 'autopulous-xdom2jso';. But this is throwing the same error in browser. No idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no responses and all I could do was fork and raise a PR myself into [autopulous-xdom2jso](https://github.com/autopulous/xdom2jso).

See my fix here: https://github.com/autopulous/xdom2jso/pull/2